# Flutter: `Provider.of(context)` cannot be found when it is a `FutureProvider()`

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a provider in my widget tree and I call `Provider.of<List<...>>(context)` to find it. If it is a provider of any type it works fine, however, as soon as change the provider from a `Provider()` (for example) to a `FutureProvider()` it doesn't work.

I haven't changed any widgets in the tree and haven't changed their position in the navigator. `Provider.of()` works fine but once I set it to be a `FutureProvider()` then it doesn't work.

Edit: My code looks something like this:

inside widget build:

```dart
return FutureProvider(
      initialData: [],
      create: (_) =>
          DatabaseService(uid: _auth.getUser()!.uid).getJournalEntries(),
      catchError: (context, error) {
        print(error.toString());
      },
      ...
}
```

Then one of the children is another widget and this is its build function:

```dart
List<JournalEntryData> entries =
        Provider.of<List<JournalEntryData>>(context);
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print(entries);
        },
        child: Text('print provider data'));
}
```

I get the following error:

Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List> above this TestButton Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that TestButton is under your MultiProvider/Provider<List>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```

The problem is that there is a provider in the widget tree:
[image: Widget Tree]

Replacing the `FutureProvider()` with any other type of provider makes it work, but I need a `FutureProvider()`.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: When I call `Provider.of()` and it is a future provider it throws an error with a red screen saying that there is no provider in the widget tree, basically it can’t find it but if i change it to any other type of provider I don’t get an error and everything works fine. I am not next to my computer right now but I will update the post with more information when I can.

Comment: Maybe add `listen: false` to your `Provider.of`? https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/313

Comment: @SilkeNL That didn't work. I updated the post to include the errors.

Comment: Could it be that you need to wrap your list in a Future? `Provider.of<Future<List<JournalEntryData>>>(context);`

Comment: @Gpack It was a problem similar to that. I needed to define the type of the `FutureProvider` and that's why it wasn't working. In my `Provider.of()` I had the type as `List<JournalEntryData>` but my `FutureProvider()` was dynamic since I didn't specify a type. It works now that I defined the type of the `FutureProvider()`.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't define the type of the `FutureProvider()` so it was `dynamic` but in my `Provider.of()` call I specified a type which caused the issue. Specifiying the type of the `FutureProvider()` should solve the issue.